What Christian ideas are found in the New Testament that are not found in the Old Testament?
Background
Inspired by What important Mormon doctrines are taught in the book of Mormon that we couldn't find in the Bible already?
The Hebrew bible contains history, religious laws, sensual poetry, creation stories, and more. But scholars have long noted a lack of systematic theology compared with other religious books (not that there isn't theology contained in the Hebrew bible).
On the other hand, authors of the New Testament make extensive and explicit theological arguments, a clear example is Epistle to the Hebrews which marked the line in the theological sand between proto-Christianity and 1st/2nd Century Judaism.
Question
What are doctrines or ideas, small or large, which are only found in the New Testament?
I am interested in all perspectives on doctrines, theology, etc that are 'new' in the New Testament. This question will require an amount of good faith from any answerers, since a post-hoc reading of the Hebrew bible could gin up support for any number of NT innovations. I'm looking for ideas that are clear in the NT but unclear or not found in the Hebrew bible.
Example answer
An example could be:


For whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it James 2:10



The idea that breaking any one of the commandments is equivalent to breaking all of them is not found in the Hebrew bible and appears to be a new doctrine found only in the New Testament


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You must eat the Flesh of God to be saved. That's pretty new.

While the above comment might seem sarcastic, it is true; the phrase "New Testament" comes from the Greek "novum testamentum," which Jesus only used to refer to His sacrificial offering at the Last Supper.  When the early Christians were assembling the collection of Apostolic writings and trying to figure out what to call the collection, one thing and one thing only stood out as being so new and so important as to have the entire collection named after it.

@Displayname the eucharist is in my answer

James 2:10 is not a good example.  See Deuteronomy 27:26.


The idea that law was given to man via angels:

Galatians 3:19

Why then the law? It was added because of transgressions, until the offspring should come to whom the promise had been made, and it was put in place through angels by an intermediary.

Acts 7:53

you who have received the law that was given through angels but have not obeyed it.

This appears solely in the New Testament and potentially extra canonical late Jewish writings like Jubilees

The idea that the snake in the garden was Satan

Revelation 12:9; 20:2 identify Satan as an ancient serpent, later Christians linked this allusion with the snake from Genesis. On the other hand, the Hebrew bible does not identify the snake as anything more than an animal.

The idea that Satan rules the world as god

Satan is called “the god of this age” in 2 Corinthians 4:4 and “the prince of this world” in John 12:31. There are very little data supporting the idea of a supernatural being besides YHVH ruling the world in the Hebrew bible.

The idea that Moses’s body was fought over by angels

Jude 9 makes a curious allusion to an angel and Satan fighting over Moses’s body. This episode is entirely absent from the Hebrew bible and appears to be a reference to the extra-canonical pseudographic Testament of Moses.

The idea that breaking one commandment means that you’ve broken the entire law

James 2:10:

For whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it

The idea that breaking any one of the commandments is equivalent to breaking all of them is not found in the Hebrew bible and appears to be a new doctrine found only in James.
The Hebrew bible lists numerous sins and punishments, such as idolatry being punished with stoning (Deuteronomy 13:6-10) whereas eating blood means being cut off from the rest of Israel (Leviticus 17:10-14). Breaking one commandment does not yield the same punishment as the others.

The names Jannes and Jambres being identified as Pharaoh's sorcerers

2 Timothy 3:8:

As Jannes and Jambres opposed Moses, so these people, of corrupt mind and counterfeit faith, also oppose the truth

These characters are not identified in the Hebrew bible, Paul appears to be relying on extra biblical traditions here.

That Enoch made prophecies about 'holy ones'

Jude 1:14:

It was also about these that Enoch, in the seventh generation from Adam, prophesied, saying, “See, the Lord is coming with ten thousands of his holy ones

Enoch makes no such prophecies in the Hebrew bible, this is a quotation from the pseudepigraphal Book of Enoch written in the late Hellenistic period.

That Melchizedek is an eternal being

Hebrews 7:3:

Without father, without mother, without genealogy, having neither beginning of days nor end of life, but resembling the Son of God, he remains a priest forever

The idea that Melchizedek had no father or mother, no beginning or end is not found in the Hebrew bible. This is a remarkably foreign idea to the Hebrew bible.

That the dead go to different places in the afterlife depending on divine criteria

The Hebrew bible portrays the afterlife as one place that all went, human and animal (Psalms 49:12, Psalms 49:14, Psalms 49:20), good and evil (Eccl 9:2-3). No one could avoid the destination (Psalm 49:9, 89:48). The New Testament portrays the afterlife as a place where rewards can be give depending on "actions", see 2 Corinthians 5:10:

For all of us must appear before the judgment seat of Christ, so that each may receive due recompense for actions done in the body, whether good or evil


Satan is a fallen angel working against God

The NT portrays Satan as a fallen angel in Luke 10:18, and portrays him as working at odds against God's plans of spreading the gospel in 1 Thessalonians 2:18. The Hebrew bible contains no references to 'Satan' falling from heaven or working against God's plans and it portrays Satan as one of many 'sons of God' who remains in God's presence in heaven and does God's bidding in Job 1:6-22.

The concept of humans judging angels

1 Corinthians 6:3:

Do you not know that we are to judge angels, to say nothing of ordinary matters?

The Pauline concept that humans will one day judge angels is a unique idea not found anywhere in the Hebrew Bible

The concept of 'Third Heaven'

2 Corinthians 12:2:

I know a person in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up to the third heaven—whether in the body or out of the body I do not know; God knows

The idea of a 3rd heaven is only found in this Pauline epistle and is absent from the Hebrew bible.

The eschatological 'antichrist'/'man of lawlessness'

2 Thessalonians 2:3-4:

Let no one deceive you in any way, for that day will not come unless the rebellion comes first and the lawless one is revealed, the one destined for destruction. He opposes and exalts himself above every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his seat in the temple of God, declaring himself to be God.

Various eschatological previews of an 'antichrist' or 'man of lawlessness' are given in the NT. The equivalent eschatological 'anti-messiah' is not found in the Hebrew bible.

'Eat[ing] the flesh of the Son of Man and drink[ing] his blood' during the eucharist

John 6:53-56:

So Jesus said to them, “Very truly, I tell you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you have no life in you. Those who eat my flesh and drink my blood have eternal life, and I will raise them up on the last day, for my flesh is true food, and my blood is true drink. Those who eat my flesh and drink my blood abide in me and I in them..."

The theology presented here is completely absent in the Hebrew bible. There is no positive example of eating/drinking blood in order to receive eternal life or otherwise.

Angels desiring to understand the gospel

The author of 1 Peter 1:12 claims angels are curious and eager to understand the mysteries of salvation:

It was revealed to them that they were not serving themselves but you, when they spoke of the things that have now been told you by those who have preached the gospel to you by the Holy Spirit sent from heaven. Even angels long to look into these things

This is absent in the Hebrew bible, where angels are servants and messengers and do not display curiosity.

Prohibition of males covering heads during prayer, calling them a disgrace

Paul prohibits Christian men from covering their heads during prayer, calling them a 'disgrace' in 1 Corinthians 11:4:

Any man who prays or prophesies with something on his head disgraces his head

The idea that head coverings are a disgrace is not found anywhere in the Hebrew bible, which actually prescribes head coverings for priests in Exodus 28:40 and indicates that they are 'for dignity':

And for Aaron’s sons also you shall make tunics and make sashes for them and make turbans for them for dignity and adornment


The prohibition of women speaking in churches

Preface: this is obviously a touchy subject but I'm simply making the point that no such prohibition is found in the Hebrew bible.
Paul instructs that women should remain silent in churches and not speak, saying, "It is shameful for a woman to speak in church." This concept is not found in the Hebrew bible.

The celebration of celibacy (pun not intended)

The NT makes several positive statements about celibacy in the gospels and Pauline epistles. Paul encourages those who can hack celibacy to follow his example in 1 Corinthians 7:8-9:

To the unmarried and the widows I say that it is good for them to remain unmarried as I am. But if they are not practicing self-control, they should marry. For it is better to marry than to be aflame with passion

In the Hebrew bible marriage and procreation are a positive and expected state. It includes positive commandments to have children, and provides laws governing marriage and family life, indicating that it takes marriage and reproduction for granted. Celibacy is not spoken of positively in the Hebrew bible.

The prohibition of oaths/swearing

The NT authors flatly prohibit swearing oaths and encourage Christians to simply let their word be their word (Matthew 5:34-37; James 5:12).
Oaths and vows are very common and regulated in the Hebrew bible in Numbers 30:2 and Deuteronomy 23:21. YHVH's name is commonly used to swear oaths upon. Swearing falsely by YHVH's name is prohibited Leviticus 19:12, so swearing truly is obviously permitted. The name אֱלִישֶׁבַע  (Elizabeth in English) means God is my oath.

'Son of man' being equated with 'Son of God', use as a title

The Hebrew expression בן־אדם simply means 'human', and in context it is often used in contrast with the divine. It is also never used as a title, every single occurrence of ben-adam lacks the definite article.
NT authors like John use the title 'son of man' and 'son of God' interchangeably. In fact later scribes rendered the phrase interchangeably, like in John 9:35 where υἱὸν τοῦ ἀνθρώπου is interchanged with υἱὸν τοῦ Θεοῦ. Further, late deuterocanonical forgeries like 4 Ezra explicitly identify 'the son of man' with a pre-existant Messiah figure.

The 'New Covenant' from Jeremiah 31 applying to non-Jews

The famous 'new covenant' from Jeremiah is made between YHVH and the House of Israel. Jeremiah 31:33 reads

כִּי זֹאת הַבְּרִית אֲשֶׁר אֶכְרֹת אֶת־בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל אַחֲרֵי
הַיָּמִים הָהֵם נְאֻם־יְהֹוָה נָתַתִּי אֶת־תּוֹרָתִי בְּקִרְבָּם
וְעַל־לִבָּם אֶכְתְּבֶנָּה וְהָיִיתִי לָהֶם לֵאלֹהִים וְהֵמָּה
יִהְיוּ־לִי לְעָם׃ (MT)
But such is the covenant I will make with the House of Israel after these days—declares Hashem: I will put My Torah into their inmost being and inscribe it upon their hearts. Then I will be their G-d, and they shall be My people.

The NT changes this verse to apply more broadly in Hebrews.
Hebrews 10:16:

Αὕτη ἡ διαθήκη ἣν διαθήσομαι πρὸς αὐτοὺς μετὰ τὰς ἡμέρας ἐκείνας, λέγει Κύριος· διδοὺς νόμους μου ἐπὶ καρδίας αὐτῶν, καὶ ἐπὶ τὴν διάνοιαν αὐτῶν ἐπιγράψω αὐτούς (NA27)
This is the covenant I will make with them after those days, says the Lord: I will put My laws on their hearts and write them on their minds

This curious change is used to make a theological point that the 'new covenant' is actually made with more than simply the 'House of Israel'.

That there is one unique 'Son of God'

The NT presents Jesus of Nazareth as the unique Son of God in John 3:16:

For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son (μονογενης υιος, monogenēs huios), that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.

The concept of a single 'son of God' is not found in the Hebrew bible. The phrase bene-elohim/בְּנֵי־הָאֱלֹהִים (sons of God) are referenced several times in different contexts. Several named characters such as Satan are called bene-elohim, such as in Job 1:6:

"One day the sons of God (בְּנֵי הָאֱלֹהִים) came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them."

However no single character is identified as 'the unique son of God' in the Hebrew bible.

The practice of exorcism, casting out of demons

The gospels portray several exorcisms, and in Matthew 10:1 Jesus gives this power to his followers:

Then Jesus summoned his twelve disciples and gave them authority over unclean spirits, to cast them out, and to cure every disease and every sickness.

Acts 19:11-16 portrays Paul performing exorcisms later on.
There are no equivalent practices anywhere in the Hebrew bible. The nearest equivalent appears in 1 Samuel 16 where music would relieve Saul of his melancholy, but there is no 'exorcism' per se where a demon is commanded to permanently leave its human host.

The theology of humans getting to sit on the Divine Throne

Revelation 3:21

To the one who conquers I will give a place with me on my throne, just as I myself conquered and sat down with my Father on his throne.

No human is promised to sit on this throne in the Hebrew bible. Ezekiel 1 and Isaiah 6 portray the Divine Throne as an unapproachable space filled with awe, and a symbol of Gods exclusive sovereignty.

Humans participating in the divine nature

The second epistle of Peter promises believers a transition from "corruption" to "participation in the divine nature":

Thus he has given us, through these things, his precious and very great promises, so that through them you may escape from the corruption that is in the world because of lust and may become participants of the divine nature (2 Peter 1:4)

Some Christian denominations interpret this to refer to a kind of apotheosis. The Hebrew bible does not promise this.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Marking my own answer as correct since it provides an enormous number of new ideas

Thanks for the list. Maybe you could add a few more consepts to your list:


Jesus is the Word (John 1)
Baptism
The Fulfillment of the law and the prophets by Jesus (Matt 5:17)
The binding and loosing of things on earth to be so in heaven (Matt 16:19 and Matt 18:18)
The custom to gather on the first day of the week. (Not so sure about this one)
The husband and wife have control over each others bodies (1 Cor 7:4)



see here for more sources on angels being the mediator in giving the law to Moses https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/129680/why-is-it-believed-that-angels-spoke-with-moses-at-sinai-when-he-spoke-with-god We can also find various others if not all references. We cannot limit the Jewish sources to rabbinic judaism anyway. They have severely broken from the tradition which is evidence from the errors like not knowing that infant is equally impure in birth and undergoes purification offering with mother. See Isaac Oliver: Gentilizing Luke's most jewish moments on academia


https://bible.usccb.org/bible/deuteronomy/33?2=#05033002
Metaphor
Nobody says that satan=god
noted as Extrabiblical, but not new
https://bible.usccb.org/bible/deuteronomy/27?26=#05027026
Are the names of Pharoah's sorcerers ideas or doctrine?
noted as Extrabiblical, but not new
Metaphor - a priest forever like Melchizidek of old (Psalm 110)
2 Maccabees 2:12:46 - There is a place after death where some are in sin and others are not
Isaiah 14:12



Wisdom 3 - Read all for context
Not noted as Extrabiblical - "Testament of Levi"
Based on a naive understing of the Antichrist
CF: Jewish Roots of the Eucharist - Brant Pitre
Read Tobit - Raphael is definitely a curious figure, but Christians believe they have knowledge man does not
16/17. it can't be generalized - see 11:16
This is practical - which is why it is tradition in some churches, not doctrine
This is Jesus' "I say to you..." preaching, it's the heart of His teaching.
Daniel 7:13



This is literally the Gospel - I agree with this one
Irrelevant if you accept the Trinity
Numbers 21:8 and others - you don't need to split hairs between exorcisms and other healings


The practice of exorcism is not in the OT? https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-exorcism/

@RevelationLad yes exorcism is not found in the Hebrew bible

@PeterTurner you don't need to split hairs between exorcisms and other healings - ... I don't follow? they're different

@avi my understanding is that when the Gospels were written all these maladies were essentially spiritual.

It does not appear that James was quoting a Hebrew text when he said whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it. Given the context, James was flagging up the hypocrisy of showing favouritism. He had just cited "the royal law found in Scripture, 'Love your neighbour as yourself'. That certainly is a quote from the ancient Hebrew scriptures, namely, Leviticus 19:18.
James then says that showing favouritism is sin, which convicts the person as being a law-breaker. His next sentence in verse 10 is the one supposed by the OP to be another quote. But it is not until verse 11 that James certainly makes another quote: he quotes two of the Ten Commandments - Exodus 20:14, Deuteronomy 5:18. His logical conclusion about becoming a law-breaker is based on the verses prior to the ones he quotes from.
So, James is not trying to bring in a new doctrine at all. He is going into the significance of how the law proves everyone to be a sinner, because nobody can keep the law perfectly. We all break it at some point or other. Having put that example aside, the question can now be answered without that impediment.
There's a saying amongst some Protestant Christians that "The New is concealed in the Old; the Old is revealed in the New."
The New Testament puts the spotlight on many parts of the Old Testament that hinted at the way the still future New Covenant would be worked out, primarily in the person of the Messiah. Many mysteries from of old can be fully understood after Messiah's resurrection. The New Testament speaks many times of various mysteries now being fully understood. Once the Person of Christ is revealed by the Father to those who are being drawn to Christ, such revelation enables the significance of the Old Testament to be appreciated as never before. See Matthew 16:13-18.
There cannot be any 'new' doctrines in the New Testament given that the whole of the Old Testament is a vital prerequisite for understanding the New Testament. The Old Covenant had to come first. That is why the writer of the letter to Hebrew Christians goes into such detail about the Old having served its purpose with the successful mission of the Messiah. (Chapters 3 through to 10.) None of that was  'new' doctrine, for its basis was entirely in the Old Covenant / Testament.
However, if anyone thinks I am wrong and gives a proven example to the contrary, I will certainly examine that.
EDIT  Further to that last sentence, and having looked at the OPs answer and comments to me, I would add that I see the OPs point and agree that, sticking only to the Hebrew scriptures, a reader of that would find many beliefs and explanations in the Greek scriptures additional (if not foreign) to their understanding. From the Christian stance, Christ’s ministry and resurrection is like a key that opens up the Hebrew scriptures to reveal depths of doctrinal meaning that will forever remain locked away to those who do not take his reality into account. As my answer is from the Christian viewpoint, I trust this Edit will accommodate my original answer while respectfully acknowledging the different Hebrew scripture viewpoint.

I provided several examples here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/102965/64519

@AviAvraham Have now looked at that. The James one I've dealt with above.  Others have nothing to do with 'important Christian doctrines'. They are largely additional details; expansions of interpretations. The Jude 9 one is known not to be from the Jude of the OT but that later book, as you said. Christians agree with you on that detail. No way is it a Christian doctrine! Nos. 7 & 8 are, likewise, nothing to do with doctrine. No. 9 takes the Hebrew account of Melchizedek to apply spiritually to the resurrected Christ, so that IS doctrine. I hope to respond to that in the link you gave.

My number 3 and 9 are quite important doctrines

@AviAvraham Yes, No. 3 is important doctrine, yet (again) it has been built up upon by what little had been said about this  spirit creature. Given that when Jesus enlarged on this, he was speaking from a place of privileged knowledge, having been in heaven before that spirit was created, he knew all about Satan. In the book of the Revelation (to the apostle John) the lid was blown off as Christ, through his angel, gave John visions and knowledge of Satan no human could ever get, going into the eternal fate of this evil one, to protect Christians from his deceptions. The others, see above.

No. 3 is important doctrine, yet (again) it has been built up upon by what little had been said about this spirit creature - gently, this appears entirely in agreement with my question and my provided answer - number 3 is new, important, and not found in the hebrew bible

@AviAvraham  I see your point and agree that, sticking only to the Hebrew scriptures, a reader of that would find many beliefs and explanations in the Greek scriptures additional (if not foreign) to their understanding. From the Christian stance, Christ’s ministry and resurrection is like a key that opens up the Hebrew scriptures to reveal depths of doctrinal meaning that will forever remain locked away to those who do not take his reality into account. I will edit that in to my answer.

"additional (if not foreign) to their understanding.", "like a key that opens up the Hebrew scriptures to reveal depths of doctrinal meaning". — Yes, there are two types of "Christian ideas": 1) Those that give additional meaning without contradicting the original understanding; 2) Those that conflict with the Hebrew scriptures. I suspect that anything in the second category is a false belief added to Christianity (either made up or imported from paganism).

That's a good edit and has earned you an up-vote.

Here are a few new doctrines:

Means by which the Gentiles inherit salvation
Something about faith in Romans
The Indwelling of the spirit of Christ in believers

In Ephesians 3, Paul tells us one: Jews and Gentiles would be combined into one entity, the church, permitting Gentiles to become heirs of the ancient promises.

For this reason I, Paul, a prisoner of Christ Jesus on behalf of you
Gentiles— 2 assuming that you have heard of the stewardship of God's
grace that was given to me for you, 3 how the mystery was made known
to me by revelation, as I have written briefly. 4 When you read this,
you can perceive my insight into the mystery of Christ, 5 which was
not made known to the sons of men in other generations as it has now
been revealed to his holy apostles and prophets by the Spirit. 6 This
mystery is that the Gentiles are fellow heirs, members of the same
body, and partakers of the promise in Christ Jesus through the gospel.
7 Of this gospel I was made a minister according to the gift of God's
grace, which was given me by the working of his power. 8 To me, though
I am the very least of all the saints, this grace was given, to preach
to the Gentiles the unsearchable riches of Christ, 9 and to bring to
light for everyone what is the plan of the mystery hidden for ages in
God, who created all things, 10 so that through the church the
manifold wisdom of God might now be made known to the rulers and
authorities in the heavenly places.

We know that this is a new, never before revealed doctrine because Paul tells us so. He point blank says it "was not made known to the sons of men in other generations".
Romans 16 ends with another declaration of mystery:

Now to him who is able to strengthen you according to my gospel and
the preaching of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the
mystery that was kept secret for long ages 26 but has now been
disclosed and through the prophetic writings has been made known to
all nations, according to the command of the eternal God, to bring
about the obedience of faith— 27 to the only wise God be glory
forevermore through Jesus Christ! Amen.

This is looking back in summary to things spoken of throughout the letter. Since some of the content of Romans is NOT new but in the Old Testament, it would require a lot of work to sort out the new and old doctrines, but Paul again is asserting that there is new doctrine in what he just shared.
In Colossians 1, Paul adds a new dimension to the mystery, that not only is the Christ divine, but that divinity shall indwell believers:

24 Now I rejoice in my sufferings for your sake, and in my flesh I am
filling up what is lacking in Christ's afflictions for the sake of his
body, that is, the church, 25 of which I became a minister according
to the stewardship from God that was given to me for you, to make the
word of God fully known, 26 the mystery hidden for ages and
generations but now revealed to his saints. 27 To them God chose to
make known how great among the Gentiles are the riches of the glory of
this mystery, which is Christ in you, the hope of glory.



a post-hoc reading of the Hebrew bible could gin up support for any number of NT innovations.

This is absolutely true and, if the NT does indeed contain additional illumination of OT content, it should be expected and not really post-hoc at all.
As given in this good question and the several good answers there are examples of newness without clear OT support and examples of apparent newness which can be supported if the NT light is applied backwards.
"It is the glory of God to conceal a matter and the honor of kings to search it out." - Proverbs 25:2
"For with thee is the fountain of life: In thy light shall we see light." - Psalm 36:9
Some of the answers and comments here seem to react strongly against the notion of anything new having been introduced in the New Covenant.  I would like to offer just two scriptures to perhaps 'soften' the conversation; one from old and one from new.

Behold, the days come, saith the LORD, that I will make a new covenant with the house of Israel, and with the house of Judah: Not according to the covenant that I made with their fathers in the day that I took them by the hand to bring them out of the land of Egypt; which my covenant they brake, although I was an husband unto them, saith the LORD: But this shall be the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel; After those days, saith the LORD, I will put my law in their inward parts, and write it in their hearts; and will be their God, and they shall be my people. And they shall teach no more every man his neighbour, and every man his brother, saying, Know the LORD: for they shall all know me, from the least of them unto the greatest of them, saith the LORD: for I will forgive their iniquity, and I will remember their sin no more. - Jeremiah 31:31-34


Then said he unto them, Therefore every scribe which is instructed unto the kingdom of heaven is like unto a man that is an householder, which bringeth forth out of his treasure things new and old. - Matthew 13:52

Perhaps the New Testament notion of the well-instructed scribe bringing forth both new and old is not so new.  It is, after all as God says through Jeremiah, a New Covenant not according to the Old Covenant.  We shouldn't be shocked if the New Covenant contains new stuff, provided we accept that it is in our midst.


For the Son of man also came not to be served but to serve, and to give his life as a ransom for many.”
Mark 10:45 RSV

As far as I can tell, there is no indication in the OT that a Messiah or "son of man" figure would suffer and take the place of a servant. (The suffering servant of Isaiah obviously is described this way, but, again as far as I can tell, there's no hint of a connection between those identities in the OT.) I think this idea is supported by the repeated confusion displayed by his disciples whenever Jesus spoke about anything along these lines.
I.e., Jesus's servant leadership style, and his route to kingship through execution, was a surprise.

The answer by Paul Chernoch mentions some of the more important doctrines, but one smaller doctrine found in the New Testament and not in the OT is that eating "unclean" food does not make one unclean.

And he [Jesus] called the people to him and said to them, "Hear and understand: it is not what goes into the mouth that defiles a person, but what comes out of the mouth; this defiles a person...For out of the heart come evil thoughts, murder, adultery, sexual immorality, theft, false witness, slander." - Matthew 15:10-11, 19 (ESV)

In a parallel passage in Mark, the comment is made in Mark 7:19 that "(In saying this, Jesus declared all foods clean.)"

The rest of this answer is a response to Avi Avraham's claim that the existence of a 3rd heaven is unique to 2 Corinthians. Paul's comment of a "third heaven" actually makes far more sense by interpreting it based how the word "heaven" is used in both the Old and New Testaments. The Hebrew word for "heavens" has a literal meaning of "heights". In both the Greek and Hebrew Scriptures, "heaven" is used in three ways:
First, "heaven" can refer to the place birds fly and where rain comes from. In other words, it can mean "sky". Deuteronomy 28:12 mentions that rain comes from there. Also, Genesis 2:19 mentions "every bird of the heavens". The same is true in Greek; see Matthew 6:26 (where the Greek word for "heaven" in some translations is translated here "air").
Second, "heaven" is where the sun, moon and stars are. Deuteronomy 17:3 forbids worship of the "sun or the moon or any of the host of heaven, which I have forbidden". (See also Jeremiah 8:2.) The same holds true in Greek; see Matthew 24:29. So then, "heaven" can in this case be translated into modern English as "outer space".
Third, there is a "heaven" where God dwells. 1 Kings 8:30 mentions that God listens from heaven. The same is true in Greek; see the Lord's prayer in Matthew 6:9.

The 'three heavens' distinction is not found in the Hebrew bible. A modern reader who distinguishes between 'sky', 'space' and 'heaven' is reading those categories back into the Hebrew. Paula Fredriksen explains this in Paul the Pagans' Apostle. The sky was not merely a layer of atmosphere surrounding the earth as it rotates around the sun in our solar system, in a galaxy, in a small part of the universe. The sky was a lower level in a series of heavens, often three to ten in number, depending on the who, when and where of an early writing

@Avi I agree the phrase "three heavens" isn't in the OT. I also agree that distinguishing between the solar system, the milky way galaxy, and other galaxies would be reading modern science into the OT. However, it is evident that the sun, moon, and stars are higher than clouds because clouds block them. That's two different heights. Both OT and NT also distinguish them from where God dwells. That's a third usage. Could you give OT examples of fourth, fifth, or tenth usages of "heights"? (Some birds fly higher than clouds, and some lower, so flight and clouds is only one "height".)

Also, I lump together the height of the sun, moon, and stars, because that's what the OT does (as in Deuteronomy 17:3 and Jeremiah 8:2).

The idea of Original Sin:

Saint Augustine (354-430) was the first theologian to teach that man is born into this world in a state of sin. The basis of his belief is from the Bible (Genesis 3:17-19) where Adam is described as having disobeyed G-d by eating the forbidden fruit of the tree of knowledge in the Garden of Eden. This, the first sin of man, became known as original sin.


Many Christians today, particularly members of the Anglican, Roman Catholic, Lutheran, Methodist, and Presbyterian Churches, subscribe to this belief. They maintain that the sin of Adam was transferred to all future generations, tainting even the unborn. Substantiation for this view is found in the New Testament (Romans 5:12) where Paul says, "Wherefore as by one man sin entered into the world, and death by sin; and so death passed upon all men, for that all have sinned. By one man's disobediance many were made sinners."

Source: Judaism's Rejection of Original Sin

How then do you and Jews understand David's confession "in sin did my mother conceive me", Psalm 51:5..?  Surely we are born with a sinful nature, inherited from our first parents.

@AndrewShanks, there's a big difference between the concepts of sinful nature (a natural desire to decide for ourselves what is right or wrong), and original sin (inheriting and bearing the guilt of our ancestors).

It is difficult to find the different teachings in the NT not found in the OT, because it will be a matter of interpretative differences and even misconception if one thinks anything in the NT does not ally with the OT. The only objective significant difference is that the revelation of the anticipated Christ of the Hebrew Bible is not according to popular expectation, and it is not easy to believe him if one relies on the mainstream understanding of the law. The abolition of the law though, and the doctrine of Christ being rejected and his role of the suffering servant was understood to an extent, but it is difficult to accept for the religious followers.
The concept of James/Jacob 2:10 of breaking one command equates to breaking of the whole law is also understood by the pre-Christian Jews. It is the same as the Halakhah of Jesus as found in the pre-Christian sources.

Berachot 24a.
Anyone who gazes even at the little finger of a woman, it is as if he gazes at the place of her nakedness

David Stern is useful in citing various Jewish sources to show the background of the NT. David Stern, Jewish NT commentary

"See also Makkot 24a." [The passage, quoted at Ga 5:14N, tells how in Psalm 15 King David reduced the 613 commandments of the Torah to eleven and concluded, "He who does these things shall never be moved." The Talmud comments, "Whenever Rabban Gamli'el fsee Ac 5:34&N, 22:3&N) came to this passage he used to weep, saying, 'Only someone who practices all these (eleven virtues of Psalm 15] shall not be moved; but anyone falling short in any of them will be moved."']
"Also see Yalkut Shim'oni on Leviticus 4:2 ['If a soul shall sin by ignorance against any of the commandments. ,.*], where it says, 'One who transgresses one commandment is as if he had transgressed them all.'"[The relevant passage of the medieval midrash, Yalkut Shim 'oni, is this: "Zayii Ra'anan says, 'Whosoever transgresses by ignorance any of the commandments is as if he had transgressed all of God's commandments." Why is this? Because one who sins consciously knows what sin he committed and what sin he did not commit, so thai he takes care not to sin; but one who sins in ignorance is as if he transgresses all the commandments, because he does not take care to keep them. Therefore it is written, 'If a soul shall sin in ignorance against any of the commandments...' (Leviticus 4:2) and, 'Who can understand his errors?' (Psalm 19:12) If it is true for unconscious sin, how much more so for conscious sin! The Holy One, blessed be he, says, 'You sin in this world because the yetzer [(evil) impulse] governs you; but in the world to come, I will take it away from you;' as it is said in Ezekiel 36:26, 'And I will take away the stony heart out of your flesh, and 1 will give you a heart of flesh.' "(Commentary to the New Testament, ad loc.)

If we have to find major theological differences, then the comparison of the mainstream theology of Christian religion with the Hebrew Bible will be apt, if we compare the sectarian dogma shift by its adherents if we go beyond comparing the Bible alone. The doctrine that God who was believed to be unchangeable and perfect in his justice, now turns against his own word to justify the ungodly while they remain ungodly, i.e. an impropriety (dishonest, illegal) act of God in the NT, according to certain sect of the Christians. This definitely turns God's nature upside down.
Renowned theologian Dr. Craig affirms his fellow Protestants in defending the theology of Luther about the shift in God's nature. Also compare the early controversy of the second century Churches of Valentinus and Marcion.

So when we come to Romans, James Dunn, says, “That God’s righteousness towards the peoples he has created includes wrath and judgment as well as faithfulness and salvation is clearly implicit in the sequences Romans 1:16-18 and 3:3-6.”[8] Those who deny that dikaiōsynē is a forensic term, Dunn says, pay insufficient attention to Romans 4:4-5, “where the forensic background is clear in the allusion to the legal impropriety of a judge ‘justifying the ungodly’. . . , and where again the thought is entirely of attributing a righteous status to one who is unrighteous.”[9] Dunn’s point is that Paul’s referring to God as “him who justifies the ungodly” (Romans 4:5) recalls the Old Testament description of the unjust judge who justifies the wicked (Proverbs 17:15), which is an abomination in the Lord’s sight. French theologian Henri Blocher remarks on “the staggering audacity of Paul’s combination of words: God who justifies the ungodly (Rom 4:5)


The only objective significant difference is that the revelation of the anticipated Christ of the Hebrew Bible is not according to popular expectation - Nearly everyone here agreed that my 3rd difference (The idea that Satan rules the world as god) is a significant difference. Satan is portrayed as a servant of God in the Hebrew bible and is nowhere shown to rule the world

I read your points, and all of them can be easily found in anti-Christian jewish sources if one is an expert or tries to find them. Also, you need to ignore the concept of Canon limitation bec it's an anachronism to impose later canonical limitation to first century Jews. You can find books like Commentary on the NT from talmud midrash for more details; also just begin search here https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/9316?lang=en Theres no reason to find meticulous parallels of all NT ref in the jewish sources, as not all ancient books survived, and pple had diverse beliefs anyway back then

I mean search "satan rule" on sefaria to see the references https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Satan%20rule&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

The OP’s answer to their own question lists 23 teachings claimed to absent from the OT which are found in the NT. As comprehensive as the list appears, there is one important teaching missing.
Romans 3:29 (ESV)

Or is God the God of Jews only? Is he not the God of Gentiles also? Yes, of Gentiles also.

The New Testament states God is the God of the Gentiles. If this is true, some things which appear to be “new” as if not present, must be understood with the “big picture” in mind.
Jeremiah 31:33

For this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel after those days, declares the LORD: I will put my law within them, and I will write it on their hearts. And I will be their God, and they shall be my people.

When given this appears to exclude Gentiles, as the OP’s answer states. Yet, is it really a proper understanding of the OT to state what God does for one He will refuse to do for another? Or does the NT properly teach God will treat Gentiles and Jews alike? That is, the NT completes what must be present in the OT despite the lack of an explicit statement.

To answer the OP, including subsequent information, there does not appear to be any new doctrine that wasn't at least hinted at in the Old Testament.
The following is to answer the specific additional comments that are basically an expanded Opening Post.  Point 5 about James and the whole Law (all or none) is the same as found in the OP.  The answer is that James is correct as told in the OT.
On point 5, James and Paul are not introducing a new doctrine by declaring if you break one law, you break them all.  This "all or none" doctrine is first found in Deut 6:25.

And it shall be our righteousness, if we observe to do all these commandments before the LORD our God, as he hath commanded us.

Gotta do them all.  The Hebrew word for all is kol, meaning all, the whole of, everything.  Strong's H3505

Ye shall therefore keep my statutes, and my judgments: which if a man do, he shall live in them: I am the LORD. Lev 18:5


And I gave them my statutes, and shewed them my judgments, which if a man do, he shall even live in them. Eze 20:11


Is this an answer to the question? Or a response to another answer? Because a comment is appropriate for the second. On Point three appears to entirely agree with my answer?

I think you're gonna have to raise all those individual points as individual questions and self-answer if you want to do this by-the-book.  We don't have a space for responses to other peoples answers here and comments would be untidy. If you don't like Avi's answer, then a downvote and link to all the questions you've raised about those points - but remember you have to ask them not as "truth" questions.

After a close reading of Avi's answer (and hypocritically attempting to answer every point as a comment), I repent of having deleted this answer - but please remember to flag for undeletion

No problem, though I had deleted many of the points of answers., but left the main one.  Just trying to spread the word of Deut 6:25 that seems to be ignored from many, many. I don't recall if I had flagged for undeletion, figuring it wouldn't happen.  So, thanks.
